# What happens when you take out the blue wool from a desert pyramid?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

New to Minecraft are desert pyramids with a bunch of colored wool in them. The wool at the very center is blue and [apparently](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/u2xc4/a_complete_list_of_everything_found_in_snapshot/) a "surprise" is deployed if you were to remove it.

[image]

What does happen exactly? The pyramid collapses? TNT fountains? Mega-charged-creeper army? An ancient curse turns into a mooshroom? Eleventy thousand chickens suddenly attack you Zelda style?

Comment: TNT Fountains: close.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a deep pit with 4 chests (which contain various items: iron and gold ingots, diamonds, [emeralds](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/Emerald), bones...) and a pressure plate in the middle. Underneath the pressure plate are 9 blocks of TNT which explode after some time if you step on it.

[image: The pit]

The player in this screenshot is in the place of the removed blue wool block. One piece of sandstone at the bottom has been removed by me to show the TNT. The room is well lit because there is a hole in the ceiling right above the blue block.

You can easily avoid the pressure plate if you dig out one of the adjacent blocks to the blue one (note that now the pit will be much darker), but the fall is still quite deadly and takes 4 hearts.

And here is a video that demonstrates this:

Comment: The best way down is to knock out the blue wool, place some water in the hole, and float down. You can easily jump out of the stream and avoid the pressure plate, and take no fall damage, and easily get back up again!

Comment: make a stone pickaxe and dig your way down safely through the walls of the 3x3 room. you can safely punch the pressure plate and remove all of the tnt, while collecting the items as well. if you want, make the temple your base and use the 4 chests to make doublechests by the main room entrance. I find it pretty successful and safe. plus you get lots of rare items and pre-made chests and a home. This is a great place to make a quarry - branch mine.